# WPD get media dimensions

Tags: c++, wpd

I want to get the width and hight of a image file on a WPD via IPortableDeviceValues.

According to the [Windows Dev Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389031(v=vs.85).aspx) every object whose type is WPD_CONTENT_TYPE_IMAGE (which they are) requires to provide WPD_MEDIA_WIDTH/WPD_MEDIA_HEIGHT but I always get a error.

```
HRESULT MyPortableDevice::getIntValue(IPortableDeviceProperties* properties, PCWSTR objectID, const PROPERTYKEY& key, DWORD* value)
{

ComPtr<IPortableDeviceValues>        objectProperties;
ComPtr<IPortableDeviceKeyCollection> propertiesToRead;

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_PortableDeviceKeyCollection,
                              nullptr,
                              CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                              IID_PPV_ARGS(&propertiesToRead));

if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    HRESULT tempHr = S_OK;
    tempHr = propertiesToRead->Add(key);      
}

if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    hr = properties->GetValues(objectID,                
                               propertiesToRead.Get(),  
                               &objectProperties); 
}   

if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

    ULONG intValue = 0;
    hr = objectProperties->GetUnsignedIntegerValue(key, &intValue);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {          
        value = &intValue;
        intValue = 0;
    }            
}

return hr;
```

I always get a error value from

```
hr = objectProperties->GetUnsignedIntegerValue(key, &intValue);
```

hr = 0x80070490 and I can't find this error code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587.aspx)

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you got is: 
Error code: (HRESULT) 0x80070490 (2147943568) - Element not found.

The reason you got this error most probably is that actually phone apps developers usually just ignore some of properties.

I have connected my phone to PC and checked some images with [WPD Information Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/portable/using-the-wpdinfo-tool) , and I get only such fields for .jpg screenshot:
[image]

I think in most cases you need to read content of the picture to stream and check it's parameters directly. Maybe in some formats you can read only some "header" part and get WIDTH and HEIGHT from there.